# 500 internal server error in ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Пытаюсь сделать прогресс бар. Но не обращается к файлу php. Выдаёт ошибку 500
вот мой ajax код

```
 function ls_ajax_test() {
    /**
     * Переменная интервала.
     * Будем запускать функцию опроса результата прогресса каждую секунду
     * @type object
     */
    var myVar = setInterval(function() {
        ls_ajax_progress();
    }, 1000);

    /**
     * Выполняем AJAX запрос к скрипту эмуляции
     */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/controllers/parser.php',
        success: function(data) {
            /**
             * По завершению работы скрипта эмуляции останавливаем таймер
             * опроса прогресса
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            clearInterval(myVar);

            /**
             * В результирующий тег пишем результат
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            $('#progress').html('DONE');
        },
    });

    /**
     * На всякий случай вернем FALSE
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    return false;
}
function ls_ajax_progress() {
    /**
     * Выполняем AJAX запрос к скрипту опроса результата прогресса
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/views/parser/progress.php',
        success: function(data) {
            /**
             * В реультирующий тег пишем то, что вернул скрипт
             */
            $('#progress').html(data);
        },
    });

    /**
     * На всякий случай вернем FALSE
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    return false;
}
```

[image: screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была решена путём прописывания полного пути к файлу и использование //